# Rotate UIImageView with same center point using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to rotate a UIImageView and keep it centered. In the image below I would like the rotated arrow (red crosshairs) center point to match up with the center point of the 0° arrow (blue crosshairs).

I have tried various anchor points but I can't seem to get it to behave as I want.

```
// Rotate
self.arrowRotatedImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
CGFloat angle = 45 * (M_PI/180);
self.arrowRotatedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

What am I missing? I'm reading through the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation)
 but I haven't been able to figure it out.

[image: iPhone screenshot of a rotated arrow on top of a non-rotated arrow]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the weird rotation issue was related to the new iOS 6 autolayout feature. Once I took some time to understand how the align constraints worked I was able to achieve the results I wanted.

If you run into weird rotation issues and are using iOS 6 with autolayout enabled chances are your constraints need adjusting.

The key is to vertically and horizontally center the image under rotation in it's parent view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the same problem has taken all my day till i've found your answer

Comment: would be nice if you shared what you learned about constraints to solve the problem.  :)

Comment: Yeah, ditto. I was looking for issue into this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, I solved it by applying a `Center X Alignment Constraint` and a `Center Y Alignment Constraint` to the `UIImageView` in question. Doing this will stop the image from moving away from its center x and y position.